# Ajax request to return element used in Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am making a POST request with Ajax to retrieve star ratings for 10 products I am showing on the website.

The request I make 10 times via php loop to build the page is:

```
function returnRating($id) {
  $.ajax({
      url: "returnRating.php",
      type: 'POST',
            data: {
                id: $id
            },
      success:function(response){
           $("#sp"+id).html(response); <- replace html for span element for each of the products
        }

  });
}
```

The ajax Php file ("returnRating.php") contains function connecting to the database and creating html code for the star rating:

```
<?php
include('db.class.php');
$bdd = new db();

$id = $_POST['id'];

function starBar($numStar, $mediaId, $starWidth) {

    ///Retrieving the rating, creating star elements to put in span for each product. Rating element class is .rating 
    return $starBar;
}    

echo starBar(5, $id, 25);

?>
```

To interact with the star ratings I am using Jquery script:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".rating").on("change", function(ev, data){  saveRating($(this).parent().attr("id"), data.to, data.to, "25px"); <- activate script saving the new rating
            });
         });

    </script>
```

My question is - where should I put the saving script? When I put it in the main page the selector doesn't work at all. I have put it in the returnRating.php file I'm requesting via Ajax and it appears to be working as it activates function saveRating. However it does it 10 times each time I click on a single star rating.

What is the correct way of using Jquery selectors on the content generated by php ajax request?

Comment: So your problem is, jQuery has no effect on AJAX generated elements?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The selector works when I enter html manually into each span but if I use ajax php request page which returns the same code it doesn't work.

Comment: Checkout the answer that i've just wrote, see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer to my question. The issue I was experiencing was **js bubbling** which was causing event to execute 10 times.

Solved by adding a line

```
ev.stopImmediatePropagation();
```

into

```
$(".rating").on("change", function(ev, data){  
    saveRating($(this).parent().attr("id"), data.to, data.to, "25px");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this:

```
$(".rating").on("change", function(ev, data){  
    saveRating($(this).parent().attr("id"), data.to, data.to, "25px");
});
```

Do this:

```
$(document).on("change", ".rating", function(ev, data) {
    saveRating($(this).parent().attr("id"), data.to, data.to, "25px");
}
```

More info about `.on` here: [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Akar. This doesn't seem to solve the issue - the ajax call stopped working altogether. Could this have something to do with not using $(document).ready(function()) ?